# Discord Bot Reads Emoji To Assign Roles

Tags: discord, discord.js, raspberry-pi4

Okay I got the emoji to work finally thanks to **~slothiful~**.

I am not attempting to have the bot assign a role based on the reaction to a message that is posted as the rules of the server.

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
        if (message.content == ':joy:' ) {
                message.member.roles.add(Yard);
        }
});
```

Thanks for the Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the Unicode versions of the emojis, because that's what the templates are converted to. This means that what you typed as `:joy:` is actually  in `message.content`.

To get the Unicode character(s) from any emoji in Discord, send `\:joy:`, for example, and copy the resulting message. Just for further clarification, in both cases, `:joy:` and `\:joy:`, `message.content` will read .

Take a look at [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages) for more info about how emojis work and collecting reactions.